# How to add a new stop to the color ramp?

Tags: python, color

How to add a new stop to the color ramp in python?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you are creating a color ramp in a node group as shown in the screenshot so i am giving you an example of creating inside of a node group. I hope you know how to add a color_ramp but still I am giving a complete example for creating a color ramp to add a new stop.

```
# Creating Color ramp
Test_fire_color_ramp = group.nodes.new(type="ShaderNodeValToRGB")

# assigning location
Test_fire_color_ramp.location = (0,0)

# Removing the First Element this is not necessary but done to show how to remove color stops
Test_fire_color_ramp.color_ramp.elements.remove(Test_fire_color_ramp.color_ramp.elements[0])

# Adding new color stop at location 0.100
Test_fire_color_ramp.color_ramp.elements.new(0.100)

# Setting the color for the stop that we recently created
Test_fire_color_ramp.color_ramp.elements[0].color = (0,0,0,1)

#creating the second stop the same way
Test_fire_color_ramp.color_ramp.elements.new(0.200)
Test_fire_color_ramp.color_ramp.elements[1].color = (0.500,0.400,0.016,1)

# Assigning position and color to already present stop
Test_fire_color_ramp.color_ramp.elements[2].position = (0.995)
Test_fire_color_ramp.color_ramp.elements[2].color = (0,0,0,1)
```

Comment: According to pep8 variable names should be `lower_case`...

Comment: @brockmann I agree with you

Comment: camelCaseRocks! Underscores are really hard to type.

Comment: Probably but pep8 is not about taste @RonJensen

Answer (score 8):

```
import bpy
from bpy import data as D

# Get a reference to the colorRamp node
cr=D.materials['Material'].node_tree.nodes['ColorRamp'].color_ramp

# enumarate the elements to the console
for e in cr.elements:
    print(e.position)

# set the left most color to green
cr.elements[0].color=(0,1,0,1)

# add a new ramp in the middle, position = 0.5
cr.elements.new(position = 0.5)

# set the middle color to red
cr.elements[1].color=(1,0,0,1)

# set the right color to blue
cr.elements[2].color=(0,0,1,1)
```