# Programming multiple colors with Color Ramp in PythonAPI

Tags: python, blender-internal-render-engine, color

Hi I am struggling to get rid of InfroError caused by ColorRamp. Is there any concise way to represent the colorRamp shown below?

[image]

My messy code

[image]

The Error Message

[image]

```
import bpy

class Shader2MainPanel(bpy.types.Panel):

bl_label = "2ndShaderLibrary"
bl_idname = "ShaderMainPanel"
bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
bl_region_type = "UI"
bl_category = "ShaderLibraryV2"
def draw(self,context):
    layout = self.layout
    row = layout.row()
    row.operator("shader.ruby_operator")

class RUBY_SHADER(bpy.types.Operator):

bl_label = "RUBY"
bl_idname = "shader.ruby_operator"


def execute(self,context):
    
   
    activeObject = bpy.context.active_object
      
    mat_ruby = bpy.data.materials.new(name="Ruby")

    mat_ruby.use_nodes = True

    activeObject.data.materials.append(mat_ruby)

    #delete the default shader   
    mat_ruby.node_tree.nodes.remove(mat_ruby.node_tree.nodes.get('Principled BSDF'))

    # material output
    mat_output = mat_ruby.node_tree.nodes.get("Material Output")

    mat_output.location = (-400,0)

    #mix_shader
    mixSDR = mat_ruby.node_tree.nodes.new("ShaderNodeAddShader")
    #connect mix_shader to material output
    mat_ruby.node_tree.links.new(mixSDR.outputs[0],mat_output.inputs[0])

    #1st glass shader
    glassA= mat_ruby.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeBsdfGlass')
    glassA.location = (-600,0)
    glassA.inputs[1].default_value=0.141

    #2nd glass shader
    glassB = mat_ruby.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeBsdfGlass')
    glassB.location = (-600,200)
    glassB.inputs[0].default_value=(0.396755,0.177888,0.201556,1)
    glassB.inputs[1].default_value=0.141

    #add 1st and 2nd glass into mix_shader
    mat_ruby.node_tree.links.new(glassA.outputs[0], mixSDR.inputs[0])
    mat_ruby.node_tree.links.new(glassB.outputs[0], mixSDR.inputs[1])

    #colorRamp
    ramp = mat_ruby.node_tree.nodes.new("ShaderNodeValToRGB")
    ramp.location = (-800,100)
    for r in ramp:
            
        ramp.color_ramp.elements[0].color = (0.215861,0,0.017642,1)
        ramp.color_ramp.elements[0].position = 0.102
        ramp.color_ramp.elements[1].color = (0.396755,0,0.032,1)
        ramp.color_ramp.elements[1].position = 0.636
        ramp.color_ramp.elements[2].color = (0.701102,0.147,0.016,1)
        ramp.color_ramp.elements[2].position = 0.794
        ramp.color_ramp.elements[3].color = (1.0,0.292,0.0,1)
        ramp.color_ramp.elements[3].position = 0.893
        ramp.color_ramp.elements[4].color = (1.0,1.0,1.0,1)
        ramp.color_ramp.elements[4].position = 1
        

    
    mat_ruby.node_tree.links.new(ramp.outputs[0], glassA.inputs[0])
    

    #Vector Math ('DOT_PRODUCT')
    math = mat_ruby.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeVectorMath')
    math.location = (-1000,100)
    math.operation = 'DOT_PRODUCT'
    mat_ruby.node_tree.links.new(math.outputs[0], ramp.inputs[0])

    #Geometry
    geo = mat_ruby.node_tree.nodes.new("ShaderNodeGeometry")
    geo.location = (-1200,100)
    mat_ruby.node_tree.links.new(geo.outputs[1], math.inputs[0])
    mat_ruby.node_tree.links.new(geo.outputs[4], math.inputs[1])

    return {'FINISHED'}

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(Shader2MainPanel)
    bpy.utils.register_class(RUBY_SHADER)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.register_class(Shader2MainPanel)
    bpy.utils.register_class(RUBY_SHADER)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Please post code as text, not image. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/189712/how-to-add-a-new-stop-to-the-color-ramp

Comment: Thanks for replying, I've embedded the coding and the link is super helpful for my case

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that by default the ramp only has two elements, so your code has to first set values for the existing elements, and then create new elements.  Assuming you wanted to leave the original leftmost and rightmost handles alone, you need something along the lines of

```
    ramp = mat_ruby.node_tree.nodes.new("ShaderNodeValToRGB")
    ramp.location = (-800,100)

    ramp_colors = [(0.215861,0,0.017642,1), (0.396755,0,0.032,1), (0.701102,0.147,0.016,1), (1.0,0.292,0.0,1)]
    ramp_positions = [0.102, 0.636, 0.794, 0.893]

    elements = ramp.color_ramp.elements
    for i in range(len(ramp_colors)):
        element = elements.new(ramp_positions[i])
        element.color = ramp_colors[i]
```

If you want to use the existing handles in your code, set them first, because adding a new element changes the indices.