# How to change ColorRamp Values in python

Tags: python, materials, scripting, add-on, color

I am not that new to blender and I am trying to create a new blender addon (will spare the details) But I need to add a random value to a colorRamp (ShaderNodeValToRGB).
When I use toolTips, it says I need to adjust element[0].position HOWEVER the console is telling me that it has no element attribute. The snippet of my code and the error message is below:

```
        ## Add First ColorRamp node W/Randomizer
        ramp1 = material_planet.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeValToRGB')
        ramp1.location = (-300, 200)
        ramp1.elements[0].position = random.uniform(0.291, 0.514)
```

[image]

Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/thomas/Desktop/Blender Addon.blend/ui_panel_simple.py", line 42, in execute
AttributeError: 'ShaderNodeValToRGB' object has no attribute 'elements'

location: :-1

Thank you for you assistance.

Comment: `ramp1.color_ramp.elements[0]`. You're missing the `.color_ramp` part.

Comment: Does [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/245705/42221) answer your question?  In addition to @scurest comment, when you create a new ramp, yo have to create the elements.