# Blender scripting: How to change texture color

Tags: texturing, scripting

I'm trying to create a picture in Blender using only Python/scripting (no animation). I have a model loaded in and I can change it's base color using active_material.diffuse_color but now I want to put a texture on the model and then change the texture color. I've googled for a while and couldn't find any good resources for how to do so.

This is what I have so far:

```
mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name="Material")
mat.use_nodes = True
bsdf = mat.node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"]
texImage = mat.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeTexImage')
texImage.image = bpy.data.images.load("../textures/texture.png")
mat.node_tree.links.new(bsdf.inputs['Base Color'], texImage.outputs['Color'])

color_ramp = mat.node_tree.nodes.new("ShaderNodeValToRGB")
mat.node_tree.links.new(bsdf.inputs['Base Color'], color_ramp.outputs['Color'])

ob = bpy.data.objects['model']
if ob.data.materials:
    ob.data.materials[0] = mat
else:
    ob.data.materials.append(mat)
```

The code correctly puts the texture on the model, but I'm not sure how to use the color_ramp node to actually change the color or if it's even the right thing to try. Thanks!

Comment: Hi and welcome! How do you want to change the color of the image? Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/189712/how-to-add-a-new-stop-to-the-color-ramp and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/201412/how-to-load-an-image-from-disc-and-assign-it-to-a-newly-created-image-texture-no/201414#201414

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks brockmann, I figured it out from your links.

````
mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name="Material")
mat.use_nodes = True
bsdf = mat.node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"]
color_ramp = mat.node_tree.nodes.new("ShaderNodeValToRGB")
color_ramp.color_ramp.elements[0].color = (0.2,0.8,0.7,1)
mat.node_tree.links.new(bsdf.inputs['Base Color'], color_ramp.outputs['Color'])
texImage = mat.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeTexImage')
texImage.image = bpy.data.images.load("../textures/Fabric.png")
mat.node_tree.links.new(color_ramp.inputs[0], texImage.outputs['Color'])

ob = bpy.data.objects['model']
if ob.data.materials:
    ob.data.materials[0] = mat
else:
    ob.data.materials.append(mat)
```
````